# @ControllerAdvice exception handling together with @ResponseStatus

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have `@ControllerAdvice` class, which handles a set of exceptions. Than we have some other exceptions, which are annotated with `@ResponseStatus` annotation. To combine both approaches, we use technique described in blog post: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc, namely in the `ControllerAdvice` we handle generic `Exception` in the following way:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
        // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus rethrow it and let
        // the framework handle it - like the OrderNotFoundException example
        // at the start of this post.
        // AnnotationUtils is a Spring Framework utility class.
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
            throw e;

        // Otherwise setup and send the user to a default error-view.
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        return mav;
    }
```

It works like a charm, however, using this technique causes error with the following text to appear in the application log:

```
2014-06-11 15:51:32.907 ERROR o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: ...
```

This is caused by this piece of code in `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`:

```
try {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: " + exceptionHandlerMethod);
            }
            exceptionHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(webRequest, mavContainer, exception);
        }
        catch (Exception invocationEx) {
            logger.error("Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: " + exceptionHandlerMethod, invocationEx);
            return null;
        }
```

Does anybody know how to combine these two approaches to exception handling properly to avoid the error in the log?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Wouldn't simply disable logging for `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` solve that?

Comment: I thought about it, but it didn't seem like a conceptual solution of the problem...

Comment: How else would you fix it without reimplementing the class and remove the log line? Why should we come up with a complex solution when it can be as simple as disable logging. Depending on your logging framework you could also create a filter which filters messages based on pattern.

Comment: @M. Deinum +1 for a simple solution.  log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver = OFF

Comment: @user3730269: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No -- I was not able to solve this in any elegant way.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I just encountered this today and found a better solution than disabling logging for `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`. Turns out that the issue can be resolved by upgrading to the latest version of the spring framework (4.3.8 worked for me). The `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` has been fixed to detect if the original exception was rethrown from an `@ExceptionHandler`. In this case, the exception is no longer logged.

Comment: May I ask for a tested code snippet, that shows it works as described? I just tested to throw the original exception from inside the method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` and it simply leads to much more error logging and not less logging ^^

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I missed this `import`:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
```

*Eclipse* didn't offer me to add it in *Quick Fix*, I added the row manually and it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with it in a slightly different way which I think solves your problem.

Since I know that basically I want to deal with 404's differently to 500s of whatever hue, I look for a NOT_FOUND status and send that accordingly, which seems to work and then you're not re-throwing the exception.

This means

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MVCExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Exception ex) throws Exception {

        // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus check if it's a 404 in which case deal with it, otherwise 500 it.
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(ex.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null) {
            ResponseStatus rs = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(ex.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class);
            if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(rs.value())) {
                res.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
                return new ModelAndView("error/404");
            }
        }

        log.error("Error while loading", ex);

        return new ModelAndView("error/500");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're throwing an exception rather than returning a `ModelAndView`. Essentially, you are trying to re-implement `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` in your `ControllerAdvice` class. You could do that (e.g. by copy/pasting code from `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver`) but aside from being duplication, that approach would also be incomplete. Spring also comes with `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` for some built-in exceptions, which this approach may not handle correctly.

Instead, what I have done is not have a catch-all handler for `Exception.class` in my `ControllerAdvice` class. I don't know if this is the best solution, but it's the best I know of.

Comment: It occurs to me that you could define your own `HandlerExceptionResolverComposite` so that you can control the ordering of the 3 default resolvers. If you put `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` and `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` ahead of `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` (which calls your `ControllerAdvice`) it should take care of these default and/or annotated exception types before calling your custom exception handling. This is untested, but if it works for you, please let me know.