# How to set an exception to resolved when using @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring

I have seen many examples for Spring usage of `@ControllerAdvice`

```java
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomHandlerExceptionResolver {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomHandlerExceptionResolver.class);

  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
  final ResponseEntity<Object> handle(@Nonnull final MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex,
      @Nonnull final HttpServletRequest req,
      @Nonnull final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    log.info("Request: {} {}\n\t\tReferer: {}\n\t\tReason: {}", req.getMethod(), getFullURL(req),
        StringUtils.trimToEmpty(req.getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER)), ex.getMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST).body(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

They more or less do the same I tried.

The result is shown in the Browser, but I see a second entry in the log.

```
2022-02-09 12:05:41.678  INFO 16252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] de.mbur.CustomHandlerExceptionResolver    : Request: GET http://localhost:8080/api/pageid/579c8d91-8996-11ec-a297-7bdb3f2d4a63?duration=Test
        Referer: 
        Reason: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Test"
2022-02-09 12:05:41.681  WARN 16252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Test"]
```

How can the second one `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` be avoided?

How can this exception been set to be resolved?

**Update:**

Now it gets even worse. Since I have this `@ControllerAdvice` the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` also complains about `BadCredentialsException`. This has not happened before.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you could just set the log level to `OFF` for `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`

Comment: No because I want to see its messages that I may have not handled so fare...

Comment: Kindly see if this is related to your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164862/controlleradvice-exception-handling-together-with-responsestatus

Comment: It looks like, but there is no solution for it...